# Ionic crosswalk app async image loading from filesystem

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I use ionic 1.3.1 for my data-driven android app with crosswalk (~14 version I guess).

I have about **3k+** of full images and **3k** of their thumbnails (I did that so it woudn't resize images as user scrolls. p.s. was that a bad idea and I shouldn't do that?) in www/img/ folder and I'm displaying them with ionic's "**collection-repeat**".

It all works great, but the app takes around 5 seconds to load itself and takes up to 70-100 mb of ram while running.

Can I async load images from filesystem ?

If so where do I put them, so they would appear in my apps folder after I build the project and how do I reference the path to each of them from code with src attribute? I guess the other way would be to make a webserver from which user downloads all the images on the first start and then store them in the apps folder, but I don't have any experience with this kind of stuff, so I would prefer the first option for now.

Please, give me some tips on how to implement this or suggest other ways to solve the problem.